# How compound shard key works to read data

Tags: mongodb, redis, sharding, nosql

I am thinking a strategy for sharding a database in Key-Value Database. I have read a lot documents and articles for sharding but no where It has been explained that how we can read data when we are using compound shard key. I have several questions related to sharding algorithm in Key-Value database.

1) Using Compound key is good idea to use in Key-Value noSQL database for sharding? As per my view I can say that it is not good idea because We do not know what kind of dataset client wants to store in my Key-Value Database system.
Please share your ideas if I am wrong.

2) Suppose first answer is yes then How I can read data when it will be queried? Suppose I have used composite shard key to store data then how can I read data when it will be queried based on only one field.

Example :

```
{
    log_type: <string>, // one of "warn", "notice", "error"
    application: <string>,
    message: <string>,
    created_on: <integer> // timestamp when created
}
```

Suppose here I have used composite key which is `(message+logtype+application)` then how read and write operations works technically. This is my main question.

Can anybody please explain me about this with my example.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing too many terms and technologies. First of all you need to choose what will your durable storage technology (usually *Mongo* if I need to choose one of the NoSQL you've tagged in your question).

Mongo isn't a key-value store but a document-oriented store (a document is basically a serialized object), and its sharding is based on indexing properties. Learn more about how to configure [sharding in Mongo on its official docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/sharding/).

In the other hand, Redis is a pure key-value store where values can be data structures like lists, hashes and sets (*and others, it's just a summary*). In Redis, sharding is based on tagging a key using curly brackets: `my:{key}:whatever`. Any key tagged with `{key}` will live in the same shard. Learn more about sharding in Redis also [on its official docs](http://redis.io/topics/partitioning).

Anyway, when you ask if using compound keys is a good idea in NoSQL world it makes me think that you need to take your time and understand how different NoSQL approaches are from relational databases. You shouldn't think about your solution this way, and **also you can't think about NoSQL as a generic approach, because each NoSQL database works differently, and your NoSQL tech of choice will require you to think things carefully to model your data in the right way**.

NoSQL is just *it's not relational*.

Comment: I have asked for "Key-Value noSQL database" not only for noSQL database. So it is good idea to use compound keys in key value pair database?

Comment: @sam_k As I said in my answer, you need to learn more about NoSQL. If you ask this in key-value world it means that you don't understand how it works, at least, Redis.

Comment: @sam_k I should answer you with other question... Does Redis have compound keys? Have you checked this point? :D

Comment: I have not read about redis, I just know that redis work on KV pair and it is not using compound keys. We can query our data based on one key only. If user will query data based on value then its hard to get data in less time. Thats correct right?